# Dropping users (and assocated data) in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

We are using old versions of oracle (its either 7 or 8), and are using exp/imp to keep database servers in sync (with some time latency).  Sort of a poor man's replication.

One of the servers is the "Primary" and one is the "Backup".  On startup, the Primary exports out its full database, the Backup will drop all of its users and then import what the Primary exported.  Then on an interval, the primary will export out incremental dumps which are imported by the backup to keep them in sync.

The "drop all of its users" part is where we are spending a lot of time.  Basically to do this, I am querying for all of the users like this:

```
select distinct owner from all_tables where owner <> 'SYSTEM' AND owner <> 'SYS';
```

And then doing a "drop USER cascade" into sqlplus based on this query.   My question is, is there a faster way to wipe out all of the users and their data than this?  I'm not sure what would help me here (relaxing constraints?  other hacks?)

Answer (score 1):

You might want to [check this out](http://www.allenhayden.com/cgi/getdoc.pl?file=ascr34.htm).

This solution truncates table before dropping em, which can give you nice speedup, especially if you have a lot of data in the tables.

Comment: Thanks for the link -- but I actually stumbled upon that yesterday.  I tried it and for our schema it took about 1:30 to do "drop <user> cascade" and 2:30 to do the truncate solution.

Comment: Anything fun in alert log? May be redolog switching too fast?

Answer (score 1):

It could be quicker to just drop the complete database, re-create it and do the imports. This is especially the case when there are many objects.

Maybe time to upgrade and use smart solutions for replciation, like [dbvisit replicate](http://dbvisit.com)?